# Problema con Angular

Tags: angular

una consulta, estoy trabajando con angular para crear una nueva aplicacion pero me esta apareciendo los mensajes que se muestran abajo en la imagen

Mas info:

-Ya reinstale NodeJS (junto con npm)

-Ya reinstale angular junto con el comando `npm cache verify` y `npm cache clean` .

-Ya ejecute el comando `git config core.autocrlf true` , tambien probe con *false* y me aparece el cartel "fatal: not in a git directory" .

-Ya probe ejecutando con la linea de comando de windows y con la linea de comando de node (sin exito)

- Ya borre la carpeta @angular en los modulos de node
- La carpeta tambien la uso para crear proyectos desde linux mint (en la misma notebook)

-Anteriormente venia funcionando bien y creaba los proyectos de manera adecuada

Gracias. Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo tienes mensajes de **advertencia**... lo que dice es que cambia los saltos de linea de (Unix) `LF` a `CRLF` (Window).... es decir... lo puedes ignorar por completo

Comment: En los archivos de texto al final de cada linea para cambiar de renglon se agrega un caracter invisible `\n en  windows` y `\n\r en linux` esa advertencia la puedes ignorar,